# Ag-Grid. How to send slots to "ag-side-bar"?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have a tool panel and I want to send slot (e.g. `<h1>Edit table columns</h1>`) to above of the search input. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time there's no way to inject HTML inside the standard columns tool panel.

If you'd like to do that you'll have to build your own tool panel component and use that instead of the default column tool panel. You can do that using the approach described here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/